# generate matrix of random integers unique per row in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to directly sample a matrix of random integers that are unique on each row?
Doing this for each row apart can be slow.

```
import random as rd
import pandas as pd

N = 1000000 # number of rows/number of draws (try N=1000)
M = 100000  # range to sample from
K = 3       # size of each sample
# note: K<=M
numbers = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=range(N))
for i in range(N):
    numbers.iloc[i,:] = rd.sample(range(M),K)

#  duration in seconds (M=100)
#  N                    1000     10.000   100.000  1.000.000
#  method in question   2.2       3.3         13         99
#  method by Nin17,     0.0085    0.1       0.57        5.6
#  i.e. list comprehension [rd.sample(range(M),K) for _ in range(N)]
```

Comment: You can look into Latin Hypercube Sampling. I believe SciPy has a method for it. Though you may need to apply an adjustment to ensure the indeces are integers.

Comment: Do you mean that each row has to be different or that the numbers in each row cannot be reused in any other row? Can numbers be repeated in one row? Also, please post a minimum reproducible example (i.e. what are `numbers`, `N`, `M`, and `K`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension is faster if N, M and K are large:

```
numbers = [rd.sample(range(M), K) for _ in range(N)]
```

Comment: you just simplified it and used a loop again!!!

Comment: the problem was that it's slow, this is a faster way

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways I know is that you can do it using `numpy`.

`numpy` has a function called `reshape()` its job is to shape the list you want to any shape like matrix.

try this code:

```py
import random as rd, numpy as np
matrix = np.array(rd.sample(range(M), K*N)).reshape(N, K)
```

in here `N` is number of `rows` and the `K` is number of `columns`.

Comment: This doesn't produce the same result as the sample code. With K=M=N=2 it results in ```ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative``` whereas the sample code is error free.

Comment: @Nin17 try to use a range equal or bigger than `N*K` for `M` and the error will be fixed.

Comment: that's my point,  on the other method you don't need to

Comment: the condition for the original method is ```M>=K``` not ```M>=N*K```

Comment: This is wholly different sample. In the question, a given integer may appear independently over multiple rows. In your solutions, once an integer appears in one row, it cannot appear in any other rows. eg. `[[0, ...], [0, ...]]`, where zero appears both in the first and second row, could be a valid output. Your solution will never produce this as output.